# A network-related or instance-specific error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to access database from a Class Library Project. I have connection string defined in App.config file like this

```
add name="EditRegionConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=testdb;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

I am trying to access this conenction string via code

```
Table<cont> table1 = new DataContext("EditRegionConnectionString").GetTable<cont>();  
var t1 = from t in table1 select t;  
//i am getting error here  
t1.FirstOrDefault();
```

Error

> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes
>   Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually use the connection string, and not just the name of it.  Try something like:

```
string conString = ConfigurationManager
                      .ConnectionStrings["EditRegionConnectionString"]
                      .ConnectionString;

Table<cont> table1 = new DataContext(conString).GetTable<cont>();
```